# Python x Sharepoint - CreateUploadSession

Tags: python, sharepoint, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to write files to Sharepoint using Microsoft Graph API (CreateUploadSession), following this link:
gist.github.com/keathmilligan/590a981cc629a8ea9b7c3bb64bfcb417

I'm able to read from sharepoint easily and already have done the process to request the token.

But when I'm trying to use this API endpoint, I'm getting an error

requests.get(f'{ENDPOINT}/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{folder_url}', headers=headers)

```
import requests
import msal
import atexit
import os.path
import urllib.parse
import os


TENANT_ID = '<your tenant id>'
CLIENT_ID = '<your application id>'
SHAREPOINT_HOST_NAME = 'yourcompany.sharepoint.com'
SITE_NAME = '<your site name>'

AUTHORITY = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + TENANT_ID
ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0'    
filename = 'test_file.txt'
folder_path = "C:/Users/svcAlteryx-DEV/Desktop"

folder_url = urllib.parse.quote(folder_path)
result = requests.get(f'{ENDPOINT}/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{folder_url}', headers=headers)
print(f'{ENDPOINT}/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{folder_url}')
result.raise_for_status()


HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!RISMyiDdukGGGNeDPsCAu_mfncDFdCNCjwSApVwoJ7R2lYZfKplTR4Lv3IkATh-p/root:/C%3A/Users/svcAlteryx-DEV/Desktop
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? The (drive_Id) was gathered by using this call (response 200):

```
result = requests.get(f'{ENDPOINT}/sites/{site_id}/drive', headers=headers)
result.raise_for_status()
drive_info = result.json()
drive_id = drive_info['id']
```

After that I'll proceed with this:

```
folder_info = result.json()
folder_id = folder_info['id']

file_url = urllib.parse.quote(filename)
result = requests.post(
    f'{ENDPOINT}/drives/{drive_id}/items/{folder_id}:/{file_url}:/createUploadSession',
    headers=headers,
    json={
        '@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior': 'replace',
        'description': 'A large test file',
        'fileSystemInfo': {'@odata.type': 'microsoft.graph.fileSystemInfo'},
        'name': filename
    }
)
result.raise_for_status()
upload_session = result.json()
upload_url = upload_session['uploadUrl']
```

Comment: What is the destination folder on the SharePoint? Does the destination folder exist on the SharePoint or should be created during upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering is a "Bad Request" error, indicating that the request you're sending to the Microsoft Graph API is incorrect. Let's go through your code and identify potential issues.

1. The first line of your code snippet is missing the `drive_id` variable. You should assign the `drive_id` value before making the request. Based on your provided code, it seems you should make the `GET` request to retrieve the drive information before proceeding with the folder creation/upload.
2. The `folder_url` variable is currently assigned with a local file path `(C:/Users/svcAlteryx-DEV/Desktop).` However, for SharePoint, you need to provide the path relative to the SharePoint site or drive. Ensure that `folder_url` contains the correct relative path to the desired folder within SharePoint.
3. In the `GET` request, you're using the `requests.get` method without including the `headers` parameter. It seems you have defined headers elsewhere in your code, so make sure to pass it as an argument to the `requests.get` method.

   ````
   import msal
   import atexit
   import os.path
   import urllib.parse
   import os

   TENANT_ID = '<your tenant id>'
   CLIENT_ID = '<your application id>'
   SHAREPOINT_HOST_NAME = 'yourcompany.sharepoint.com'
   SITE_NAME = '<your site name>'

   AUTHORITY = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + TENANT_ID
   ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0'
   filename = 'test_file.txt'
   folder_path = "/sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/folder/subfolder"  # Replace with the correct SharePoint folder path

   #Make sure to assign the drive_id before using it in the GET request
   result = requests.get(f'{ENDPOINT}/sites/{site_id}/drive', headers=headers)
   result.raise_for_status()
   drive_info = result.json()
   drive_id = drive_info['id']

   folder_url = urllib.parse.quote(folder_path)
   result = requests.get(f'{ENDPOINT}/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{folder_url}', headers=headers)
   result.raise_for_status()

   #The rest of your code follows...```
   ````

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. 

When you say folder_url must be a sharepoint location, I get that, that I need to assign a local within sharepoint.  But since I’m trying to upload a file to sharepoint, I need to  assign the origin file path for the file that will be uploaded to sharepoint. The driver ID is already related to the location on sharepoint I’m uploading my file to…

Comment: this is the link where I'm getting the code from:
https://gist.github.com/keathmilligan/590a981cc629a8ea9b7c3bb64bfcb417

Comment: @TanaiGoncalves the folder path should relative path within the SharePoint site rather than an absolute file path on the local machine.

Comment: Ok so I should assign the local path from the file I want to upload with this endpoint?f'{ENDPOINT}/drives/{drive_id}/items/{folder_id}:/{file_url}:/createUploadSession',

Comment: @TanaiGoncalves Based on my understanding from the code `gist.github.com/keathmilligan/590a981cc629a8ea9b7c3bb64bfcb417 `, the `filename = 'Large File.pdf'` means the name of the file that will be uploaded to SharePoint(I assume that the file exists in the same directory as the Python script that is being executed) and `folder_path = 'General' `means the path of the folder within the SharePoint site where you want to upload the file. am I correct?

Comment: @TanaiGoncalves If you find a solution to this, please share it with us.

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Comment: Hey @AmithAG you were right, and I should've assigned the Sharepoint file path instead of the local path.
But 1 main thing is that I was using this endpoint to get the Drive ID:
f'{ENDPOINT}/sites/{site_id}/drive'
But this delivers the drive ID for the main site and not the site I wanted, so I kept getting that error, so I changed it to 
f'{ENDPOINT}/sites/{site_id}/drives' 
and this gave me a list of drive IDs and I was able to assign the right one and get all the way through.
Thank you all for the help.